# Drop down menu not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

When I move the cursor away from the About Me li element the drop down menu disappears , I know it will work if I adjust the top attribute , but I want to keep a little gap between the navigation bar and the drop down menu , I dont want js or jquery fixes, right now I just want to know if this can be done with just CSS .

**HTML & CSS**

```css
navboy {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 50%, #cccccc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 50%, #cccccc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 50%, #cccccc);
}
.nav {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
ul.nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  font-size: 110%;
  color: #000;
}
.nav li #embed {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
  left: -20px;
  top: 140%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 97%, #cccccc);
  ;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.nav > li:hover > #embed {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12">
      <div class="headshot push_5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_12 navboy">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" id="me">About Me</a>
          <ul id="embed">
            <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">My Journey</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dwdfc0by/

Comment: What have you tried? What grid system are you using there? And is this the most [minimal, complete, verifiable](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example? That last one should help you pinpoint the problem

Comment: I looked on codepen, stack overflow. W3schools as well but the answers are not what I am looking for. I am using 960.gs framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use transitions. Here's an example. Hope it helps

```css
navboy {

    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 50%, #cccccc);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 50%, #cccccc);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 50%, #cccccc);
}


.nav {

    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.nav li {

    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

ul.nav a {

    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    font-size: 110%;
    color: #000;
}

.nav li #embed {

    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:150px;
    left:-20px;
    top:140%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #999999 0.1%, #bfbfbf 97%, #cccccc);;
    border-radius: 10px;
     transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1000ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.nav > li:hover > #embed {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<body>

    `<div class="container_12" >
        <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="headshot push_5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12 navboy">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#" id="me">About Me</a>
                    <ul id="embed">
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">My Journey</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you Stormhashe for your time and your suggestion , it works like a charm. I guess the problem was with the display property, instead of which I should have used the visibility property ?  Because i tried to use transition but it didn't work earlier with the display property

Comment: Cool. Transitions doens't work with display, but will with visibility ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by positioning the dropdown immediately below the menu item, and separating the dropdown from the menu item by giving it some top padding.

Here's a working demo (I've trimmed your code down to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make it useful for anyone else who runs into the same problem)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 0 0; /* changed this */
  margin: 0;
  width: 150px;
  left: -20px;
  top: 100%; /* changed this */
}
li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Download</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">My Journey</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```